# Angular js - LocationProvider HTML5mode() and urls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-rewriting, location-provider

i've enabled the

`locationProvider.HTML5mode(true);`

then i putted on top of index.html :

```
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
 <base href="/projects/www/#/" />
```

So if i browse the site using internal links for example(#/users) everything works and urls are re-writed from `projects/www/#/users` to `projects/www/users`

BUT if i go directly by browser to `projects/www/users` i get page not found.

The only one direct url that works is :

```
projects/www/
```

What this could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i fixed it was to add some server side htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /Projects/www
# Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```